# DI in a singleton class in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm working with some legacy code where we have providers that are implemented as singletons, e.g., a typical provider looks similar to this:

```
export class MCMProviderImplementation implements IProvider {
    private static instance: null|MCMProviderImplementation = null;
    public static getInstance(): MCMProviderImplementation
    {
        if (this.instance === null) {
            this.instance = new MCMProviderImplementation();
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
    // other private and public methods
}
```

I would like to actually make use of the Nestjs' DI mechanism, make this class injectable and let the `ioC` do the instantiation. For example, I would love to inject the `HttpService`, but obviously, doing it this way is impossible:

```
@Injectable()
export class MCMProviderImplementation implements IProvider {
    private static instance: null|MCMProviderImplementation = null;
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
    public static getInstance(): MCMProviderImplementation
    {
        if (this.instance === null) {
            this.instance = new MCMProviderImplementation();
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
    // other private and public methods
}
```

I cannot just rewrite this legacy code completely, at least it should be done gradually and getting rid of these constructions is impossible at the moment.
But nevertheless, I'd like to find some decent workaround that would, on one hand, allow me to use the `HttpService` (from `@nestjs/axios`) and on another hand would bring me closer to the native NestJs approach where the `ioC` handles dependencies.

Comment: Does this legacy code makes use of NestJS modules or NestJS at all? Or is it purely independant and what you want to do is to integrate NestJS to this?

Comment: @reginald I would say it does not use NestJS that much, yes, there are two modules: "inner" and "outer" and two controllers with the corresponding names that belong to the corresponding modules and that's it. I'd like to actually start using NestJS but this singleton approach breaks the whole DI mechanism...

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that?